# How to run typeperf from batch file?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, performance, batch-file

How to run commands like

```
typeperf "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1
```

from batch file?

Ran from command line this command outputs something monstrous, while ran from bat file it prints

```
Error: No valid counters.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to double the percent sign.
From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634

> Using a percent sign (%) in a batch file requires that two percent signs (%%) be specified.
> (...)
> MS-DOS uses %1, %2, ... %9 as replaceable command line parameters. For example, before executing the command ECHO %1, %1 will be replaced with the first parameter passed to the batch file. %0 is replaced with the command used to execute the batch file.
>
> A single percent sign on a line is treated as a "nul" character in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using double % signs you could also use a config file for your counter settings like this:

tp.cfg:

```
\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
\Memory\Page Faults/sec
```

Then in your batch file call:

> typeperf -cf "tp.cfg"